# Difference between Python console and Terminal in PyCharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, console

I am a beginner in Python. I started using PyCharm recently but I don't know what's the difference between Terminal and console. Some of the commands in Terminal do not work in console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before we can talk about the differences, we need to talk about what the two are in practice. The Terminal, essentially replaces your command-prompt/power-shell on windows and the terminal app on Mac, giving you a way to access them *without leaving PyCharm*.

[image]

The PyCharm console on the other hand, is a more advanced version of the "Python Console", which allows you to run bits of Python. It is also called the Python REPL or **R**ead **E**val **P**rint **L**oop

[image]

You can invoke the Python Console from the terminal as well.

Comment: That is a nice powerline prompt, do you have a custom configuration?

Answer (score 5):

The **terminal** is your bash or windows command line where you can execute **shell** or **windows "cmd.exe"** commands like:

```sh
$ cd /
$ ls
$ echo "Hello world!!!"
```

The **Python console** is your interactive console where you can execute **python code**

```py
>>> x, y = 1, 2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> x + y
3
>>> print("Hello world!!!")
Hello world!!!
```